# Float right element not floating entirely right

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-transitions

I have two columns of boxes. There is the left and right side. For some reason the right side isn't floating all the way to the end of the container. I do not have any margins stopping it from doing this, so I am unsure of why it isn't going all of the way over.

You can see here in the fiddle:

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/r10knzpb/)

If you look at the small text/note that says 'click a service to find out more' that it is floated all of the way to the right and sits on the end of the container. The right side tabs need to be just as far over right as those.

Also, side note. You can see I have a hover effect that pulls a new background color from the left to the right. I am unsure of why the background color doesn't transition off like it does when it slides on. I have the transition code to the main element.

Does anyone know why these two things aren't working?

```
#service-tabs {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0;
    height: auto;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#service-tabs-container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#service-tabs-container-title {
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
#service-tabs-container-title2 {
    color: #578570;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: left;
}
#service-tabs-container-note {
    margin: 40px 0;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-align: right;
}
#service-tabs-left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#service-tabs-right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.service-tab-block {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 3.5em 20px;
    /*padding: 1em 25px;*/
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #578570 50%);
    background-size: 201% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    transition:width 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease;
}
.service-tab-block.active {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
.service-tab-block:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    background-position: bottom left;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
}


<div id="service-tabs">
  <div id="service-tabs-container">
    <div id="service-tabs-container-title">WHAT WE OFFER</div>
    <div id="service-tabs-container-title2">Our Services</div>
    <div id="service-tabs-container-note">* Click a service to find out more.</div>
    <div id="service-tabs-left">
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab1">DEMOLITION</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab2">CONCRETE CRUSHING</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab3">SCRAP METAL RECYCLING</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="service-tabs-right">
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab4">ASSET RECOVERY</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab5">FOUNDATION REMOVAL</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab6">SITE WORK</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note is not moved to extreme right as its parent has a width 70%. It extends rightmost with respect to its parent

Comment: Yes, I am aware. " floated all of the way to the right and sits on the end of the container."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/r10knzpb/6/) (colored the left/right floats so you can see what happens)

Because of these 2 properties in your CSS rule

```
.service-tab-block {
    padding: 3.5em 20px;
    width: 85%;
```

I changed/added it to this

```
.service-tab-block {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);   /* compensate for the padding and margin */
    ....
}
#service-tabs-right .service-tab-block {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

---

For the transition, change

```
transition:width 0.2s ease;
-webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease;
```

to

```
transition:all 0.2s ease;
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
```

Comment: If I make it 100% width they blend together. I tried doing something like this `#service-tabs-right.service-tab-block {
  margin-left: 15%;
}`, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @Becky Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here the possible solution with working transitions

CSS

```
#service-tabs {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0;
    height: auto;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#service-tabs-container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#service-tabs-container-title {
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
#service-tabs-container-title2 {
    color: #578570;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: left;
}
#service-tabs-container-note {
    margin: 40px 0;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-align: right;
}
#service-tabs-left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#service-tabs-right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.right1{
margin-right: -3%;
}

.service-tab-block {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 3.5em 20px;
    /*padding: 1em 25px;*/
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 30px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #578570 50%);
    background-size: 201% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    transition:width 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
}
.service-tab-block.active {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
.service-tab-block:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition:0.4s all ease-in;
    background-position: bottom left;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="service-tabs">
  <div id="service-tabs-container">
    <div id="service-tabs-container-title">WHAT WE OFFER</div>
    <div id="service-tabs-container-title2">Our Services</div>
    <div id="service-tabs-container-note">* Click a service to find out more.</div>
    <div id="service-tabs-left">
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab1">DEMOLITION</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab2">CONCRETE CRUSHING</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab3">SCRAP METAL RECYCLING</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="service-tabs-right" class="right1">
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab4">ASSET RECOVERY</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab5">FOUNDATION REMOVAL</h1>
        <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab6">SITE WORK</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this to your css

```
#service-tabs-right .service-tab-block{
  float: right;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Edited Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
#service-tabs {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0;
  height: auto;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#service-tabs-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#service-tabs-container-title {
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
#service-tabs-container-title2 {
  color: #578570;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
}
#service-tabs-container-note {
  margin: 40px 0;
  font-size: .7em;
  text-align: right;
}
#service-tabs-left {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}
#service-tabs-right {
  float: right;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.service-tab-block {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 3.5em 20px;
  padding: 1em 25px;
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #578570 50%);
  background-size: 201% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right;
  transition: width 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.service-tab-block.active {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
.service-tab-block:hover {
  background-position: bottom left;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="service-tabs">
  <div id="service-tabs-container">
    <div id="service-tabs-container-title">WHAT WE OFFER</div>
    < <div id="service-tabs-container-title2">Our Services</div>
  <div id="service-tabs-container-note">* Click a service to find out more.</div>
  <div id="service-tabs-left">
    <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab1">DEMOLITION</h1>
    <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab2">CONCRETE CRUSHING</h1>
    <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab3">SCRAP METAL RECYCLING</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="service-tabs-right">
    <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab4">ASSET RECOVERY</h1>
    <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab5">FOUNDATION REMOVAL</h1>
    <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab6">SITE WORK</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below the codes.

If we partition the div's, we should give css of parent width:100% after that each div having 50% of width.

```
#service-tabs-container {
    clear: both !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
<div id="service-tabs-container">
        <div id="service-tabs-container-title">WHAT WE OFFER</div>
        <div id="service-tabs-container-title2">Our Services</div>
        <div id="service-tabs-container-note">* Click a service to find out more.</div>


      <div class="" style="width:100%">
            <div id="service-tabs-left">
                <h1 id="service_tab1" class="service-tab-block">DEMOLITION</h1>
                <h1 id="service_tab2" class="service-tab-block">CONCRETE CRUSHING</h1>
                <h1 id="service_tab3" class="service-tab-block">SCRAP METAL RECYCLING</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="service-tabs-right">
                <h1 id="service_tab4" class="service-tab-block">ASSET RECOVERY</h1>
                <h1 id="service_tab5" class="service-tab-block">FOUNDATION REMOVAL</h1>
          <h1 id="service_tab6" class="service-tab-block">SITE WORK</h1>
      </div></div>
```

Hope you this will help to you.